# I'm trying to use window.location.href in a Loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I want to redirect a user to a new page if their login details are correct. However, when I use the `window.location.href("portal.html")` in a simple if statement to check if user details match an already stored data in a variable, it works, but when I use it in a for loop to loop through an array of stored data it doesn't render the the `portal.html` page.

please help, Thanks.

```
 for(let i = 0; i<= objPeople.length; i++){
      if(name === objPeople[i].username && pass === objPeople[i].password){
        window.location.href="portal.html"
        
        return
      
      }
     
    } console.log("incorrect login details");
```

Comment: use break instead of return

Comment: Are you sure the username and password match?

Comment: Can you show us an example of the working code as well as what is inside your `objPeople` array as well as `name` and `pass`?

Comment: use i < objPeople.length instead of i <= objPeople.length It will break if no data matches.

Comment: @AdnanAhmed I used Break and it worked, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `find` instead of a `for` loop:

```
if (objPeople.find(x => x.username === name && x.password === pass))
  window.location.href="portal.html"
else
  console.log("incorrect login details")
```

I tested your code and like Adnan Ahmed mentioned it does not work because of the `return` statement. It should be `break`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
 let matches = false;
 for(let i = 0; i<= objPeople.length; i++){
  if(name === objPeople[i].username && pass === objPeople[i].password){
   matches = true;
  
  }
} 
if(matches){
 window.location.href="portal.html"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just remove `return`. `return` statement prevents the redirection to the new page. I tried following example and it works:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  if (i === 10)
    window.location.href = "https://google.com";
}
```